# Misunderstanding JavaScript type system

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

```
var foo=[0];
if(foo) alert('first');
if(foo==true) alert('second');
```

Tell me please, why the second alert doesn't work? In first alert `foo` casts to `Boolean`, so

```
Boolean(foo);
//true
```

If "foo" is "true", why doesn't the second alert work?

Comment: Since when is an Array equal to `true`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here,

**if( foo)** alerts because foo isn't null and the condition evaluates to true.

However, this doesn't mean that foo itself is equal to true, hence the second alert doesn't show.

Answer (score 1):

Because initially `foo` is an `Array`, not a `Boolean` and you are comparing `foo` to a boolean value. The `if (...)`-statement evaluates to true or false and `foo == true` evaluates to false here. If you used `if (!!foo == true)` (or just `if (!!foo)`) or `if (foo != null)` or `if (foo)` the second alert would have fired.

Answer (score 1):

Because there's a difference between the conversion of `foo` to boolean (which works for an Array) and the comparison of `foo` to `true`.

In the latter case, it's a comparison *without* a conversion, and `foo` clearly is not the same as `true`. Note that a conversion does still take place: `foo == true` is `false` which is finally "converted" to `false` for the `if`. :)

Comment: There is a special operator "compare with type check" === in JS and PHP. So operator "==" makes comparison WITH type casting.

Comment: @Scalar: I like how you're trying to teach me something that directly contradicts the behaviour you've observed that you asked for help on in the first place.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Sorry, may be i don't understand you, cause my English is not very good :-[ I thougth that you dont see difference between "==" and "===". My first question is the last thing i don't understand in JS type system.

Comment: `===` is the strict equal operator and only returns a Boolean true if both the operands are equal and of the same type. `==` is the equal operator and returns a boolean true if both the operands are equal... which they're still not.

Comment: But, for example `[1]==true;//true, wow!` and `[0]==true;//false` and `[0]==false;//true`, but `[2]==true;//false` and `[2]==false;//false`. I understand how it works, now, when i read ECMA-262 (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), but i still don't understand algorithm of **if** statement expression check.

Comment: Ok, now i get it. `if(foo)` is equal to `if(Boolean(foo))`, that's all. JS type system is very dangerous.

Comment: @Scalar: Yea. I don't see how it's dangerous. Most (if not all) languages with this kind of syntax function in the same way.